# Usando tabs, controlador solo me reconoce un modelo, ¿ como puedo hacer para que me reconozca mas de un modelos?

Tags: php, validación, yii

Buenas a todos, con respecto a mi duda es que estoy usando tabs en una vista pero cada pestaña va a un modelo diferente, y por consiguiente guardan en sus respectivos modelos, pero a al momento de hacer el guardado de datos solo paso por post un solo modelo y no consigo como me reconozca el otro, probé usando  $mimodelo->validate(); pero tampoco me reconoce el otro modelo, también me gustaría saber si puedo retornar de ids diferentes en el momento del salvado. acá dejo parte de mi código para ver si pueden ayudarme

Vista

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'registro_cobranza-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        ));
?>



<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('validar2', '   

    $("#' . CHtml::activeId($estatus_cobranza, 'id_catalogo') . '").change(function(){
        var valor =$("#' . (Chtml::activeId($estatus_cobranza, "id_catalogo") ) . ' option:selected").val();

//alert(c);return false; este jquery es para la bandera que tengo en el controlador, ya que yo le doy a un select para que aparezcan las pestañas que necesito, son dos por cada tab, pero una siempre es la misma que es la de observaciones.

            if(valor=="2"){

                $("#paga").show();
                $("#c").hide();
                $("#Pagos_valor").val(valor);
            }else{

                $("#paga").hide();

            }
                if(valor=="3"){
                $("#Pagos_valor").val(valor);
                    $("#nopaga").show();
                     $("#c").hide();

                }else{
                    $("#nopaga").hide();

                } 




    });

'); ?>

<h3 align="center">Registro de cobranza</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($estatus_cobranza, 'descripcion'); ?>
        <?php
        $this->widget(
                'booster.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
            'model' => $estatus_cobranza,
//            'name' => 'descripcion',
            'attribute' => 'id_catalogo',
            'data' => CatalogoCobranza::FindMaestrosByPadreSelect(1),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style' => 'width: 100%',
                'placeholder' => '--Seleccione--',
                'multiple' => false,
            ),
        ));
        ?>    


    </div>
</div>

<br>
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'valor'); ?>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="paga" style="display:none">

    <?php

    $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'type' => 'pills',
        'justified' => true,
        'tabs' => array(
            array('active' => true, 'label' => 'Datos del pago',
                'content' => $this->renderPartial(
                        'pago_multa', array('id' => $id,
                    'montoMulta' => $montoMulta,
                    'model' => $model,
                    'multa_sugerida' => $multa_sugerida), true),
                'linkOptions' => array('id' => 'a')
            ),
            array('label' => 'Observaciones',
                'content' => $this->renderPartial('Observaciones', array('model' => $model, 'form' => $form,
                    'observaciones' => $observaciones,
                    'archivos' => $archivos), true),
                'linkOptions' => array('id' => 'c')
            ),
        ))
    );
    ?>


</div>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="nopaga" style="display:none">


    <?php

    $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'type' => 'pills',
        'justified' => true,
        'tabs' => array(
            array('active' => true, 'label' => 'Residente',
                'content' => $this->renderPartial('../residente/no_pago_multa', array('montoMulta' => $montoMulta,
                    'form' => $form,
                    'residente' => $residente,
                    'multa_sugerida' => $multa_sugerida,
                    'medidas_preventivas' => $medidas_preventivas), true),
                'linkOptions' => array('id' => 'b')
            ),
            array('label' => 'Observaciones',
                'content' => $this->renderPartial('Observaciones', array('form' => $form,
                    'observaciones' => $observaciones,
                    'archivos' => $archivos), true),
                'linkOptions' => array('id' => 'c')
            ),
        ))
    );
    ?>


</div>


<div class="row text-right">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

<?php
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'buttonType' => 'link',
//            'id' => 'blanqueo_formulario',
    'label' => 'Cancelar',
    'context' => 'danger',
//            'url' => $this->createUrl('vDistribucionProductorRubros/admin'),
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'redirect'),
));
?> 

        <?php
        $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType' => 'submit',
            'id' => 'chequeo',
            'context' => 'success',
            'label' => 'Siguiente',
        ));
        ?> 



    </div>
</div>

</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Controlador

```
public function actionCreate($id = 1) { // ese $id=1 es solo en modo de prueba
$model = new Pagos;
$residente = new Residente;  
$multa_sugerida = new MultasSugeridas;
$estatus_cobranza = new CatalogoCobranza;
$medidas_preventivas = new MedidasPreventivas;

if (isset($_POST['Pagos'], $_POST['Residente'])) {
            $guardar = (int) $_POST['Pagos']['valor']; // este valor es una simple bandera que traigo de la vista.

 if ($guardar == 2) {

                $model->attributes = $_POST['Pagos'];
                $model->cantidad_dinero = (int) $_POST['Pagos']['cantidad_dinero'];
                $model->fk_modo_pago = $_POST['fk_modo_pago'];
                $model->fk_origen_pago = 15;
                $model->fk_estatus_pago = 2;
                $model->fk_banco = $_POST['fk_banco'];
                $model->cod_referencia = $_POST['Pagos']['cod_referencia'];
                $model->fecha_pago = Generico::formatoFecha($_POST['Pagos']['fecha_pago']);

              $model->id_usuario_creador = Yii::app()->user->id;
            } else if ($guardar == 3 ) {


                $residente->attributes = $_POST['Residente'];
                $multa_sugerida->attributes = $_POST['MultasSugeridas'];
                $medidas_preventivas->attributes = $_POST['MedidasPreventivas'];
                $multa_sugerida->unidad_tributaria = (int) $_POST['MultasSugeridas']['unidad_tributaria'];
                $residente->id_medida_preventiva = (int) $_POST['Residente']['fk_medida_preventiva_desc'];
                $model->fk_origen_pago = 15;
                $model->fk_estatus_pago = 3;
['id_archivo_adj'];
                $medidas_preventivas->medidas_preventivas = $_POST['MedidasPreventivas']['fk_medida_preventiva_desc'];
$residente->id_usuario_creador = Yii::app()->user->id;

            }
            if ($model->save()) // aca es donde pregunto lo de retornar los ids diferentes para la bdd, me imaginé algo como esto, pero no funcionó
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id_pago));
            if ($residente->save()) {
                 $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $residente->id_residente));
            }
        }
```

muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Los tabs tienen que estar dentro de un solo tag form, tambien debe haber un solo submit para todo el formulario como en el siguiente ejemplo para que las entradas de todos los modelos se vayan en el mismo request hacia el servidor.

```
<Form>
 <div name="tab1"></div>
 <div name="tab2"></div>
 <div name="tab3"></div>
 <input type="submit"/>
</Form>
```

Comment: Pido disculpas, olvidé poner los tabs, ya edite el texto, para que vean como lo tengo.

Comment: Mira el html generado en el explorador y verifica si los tabs estan dentro del tag <Form></Form>

Comment: si , están dentro de el tag form.

Comment: Busca la forma de definir los controles para cada una de las propiedades del modelo, asignandole al mismo tiempo el modelo al que pertenecen como en el siguiente ejemplo Emails es el nombre del modelo, la propiedad es 'email':

<?php echo $form->textField(Emails::model(), ‘email’, array(‘size’ => 60, ‘maxlength’ => 250)); ?>

Comment: Una vez teniendo nombrados los elementos con su respectivo modelo y propiedades ya puedes accederlos desde el controlador.